# How to Conditionally SET in Cypher depending on parameter?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When voting on a node, I would like to register the points related to the vote. However, I would also like to keep track, in separate properties, of the amount of negative and positive points.

Here's a sketch of what I'm trying to achieve, even though it doesn't work:

```
CREATE   (u:User)
        -[v:VOTES_ON{ points: $points }]
       ->(i:Item)

CASE
  WHEN $points > 0 SET i.points_up = COALESCE(i.points_up, 0) + $points
  ELSE SET i.points_down = COALESCE(i.points_down, 0) + $points

SET i.points = COALESCE(i.points, 0) + $points
       
RETURN u, v, i
```

(I'm using Neo4j's JavaScript's driver, that's the reason for `$points`.)

Is there a way of doing this in Cypher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the APOC procedure [`apoc.do.when`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.do/apoc.do.when/) to do conditional if-then-else writes. There is also a more general procedure, [`apoc.do.case`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/overview/apoc.do/apoc.do.case/) for more complex conditional writes.

For example:

```
CREATE (u:User)-[v:VOTES_ON {points: $points}]->(i:Item)
WITH u, v, i
CALL apoc.do.when(
  $points > 0,
  'SET i.points_up = COALESCE(i.points_up, 0) + points RETURN i',
  'SET i.points_down = COALESCE(i.points_down, 0) + points RETURN i',
  { i: i, points: $points }
)
YIELD value AS _
SET i.points = COALESCE(i.points, 0) + $points
RETURN u, v, i
```

(Note the `RETURN i` statement in the `apoc.do.when` call, so that we get back the value and then return it later on.)

Comment: Do you know why we need the `YIELD` statement after calling the APOC procedure? Also, is this really the only way of doing if-then-else logic through Cypher, there is no more native way of doing this?

Comment: Also, I don't know why, but once I add the APOC procedure, it stops returning any records? It does work, I just don't get anything `RETURN`ed.

Comment: I fixed the query so that the `apoc.do.when` call returns a value, which seems to be required in order for `RETURN` in the main query to work. Also, `YIELD` is (usually) required when `CALL`ing a procedure (see [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call/)), even if you don't use the yielded result. My query just renames the yielded result to `_` to hint that it is ignored.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Just tried to reproduce things and this time it worked, have no idea why, it seems identical.

Comment: The 2 Cypher statements passed to `apoc.do.when` now `RETURN` a value.